# How can I extend the user table in identity in Blazor Server Side?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor

Is there any way to add additional fields in the User table in identity Blazor? because I have many user information such as firstname lastname and others and i want to bring all these when the user is logging in.

Comment: There is plenty of information on adding properties on ApplicationUser. Please research before asking. Try googling "msdn modify ApplicationUser"

Answer (score 2):

To add custom user properties in ASP.NET Core Identity User table, you need to do the following steps:

1. Create a Custom ApplicationUser class which inherits the IdentiyUser:

   ```
    public class ApplicationUser: IdentityUser
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string CustomTag { get; set; }
        public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
    }
   ```
2. Update the ApplicationDbContext as below:

   ```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRoles { get; set; } //custom Idnetity Role
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder); 
        }
    }
   ```
3. Update the Identity Configuration in the ConfigureServices method:

   ```
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                 .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                 .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                 .AddDefaultUI();
   ```
4. Enable migration and update the database with the following commands:

   ```
    Add-Migration CustomUserData
    Update-Database
   ```
5. Check the database via [SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15).

   [image]
6. Use [Scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) generate the relate identity pages, such as: login, logout. Then, you can update the page content to base on the ApplicationUser model.

   [Note] In the Identity Page, they might still use the IdentityUser model, you need to change it to ApplicationUser.

More detail information, see the following tutorials:

[Add, download, and delete custom user data to Identity in an ASP.NET Core project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

[How to add Custom User Properties in ASP.NET Core Identity](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-custom-user-properties/)